React Select clear selected value when changing another selector
I have two selectors using React-Select, the Post select component should be automatically fulfilled by changing Category select component. These 2 components are both in Blog components, and each of them has their own API call to get data source as option. BTW, we use formik to handle submit.
The problem is that the selected value of Post component can't be changed when changing Category, but the options are refreshed.
const Blog = () => {

// Api call to get options



<Select
    options={categoryOptions}
    defaultValue={categoryDefault}
    placeholder='Category'
/>

<Select
    options={postOptions}
    defaultValue={PostDefault}
    placeholder='Post'
/>

}

